# Evaluate $I(x)=\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{x^2t^2}\frac{dt}{(\frac{c}{xt}-\frac{mt}{x})^2+1}$

Tags: integration

> $$I(x)=\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{x^2t^2}\frac{dt}{(\frac{c}{xt}-\frac{mt}{x})^2+1},$$

I used
$$u=\frac{c}{xt}-\frac{mt}{x}$$

and

$$du=-\left(\frac{c}{xt^2}+\frac{m}{x}\right)dt$$
but I'm not able to find the limits at $t=0$ and $t=\infty$. Neither are straight forward to use as
$$\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{1+t^2}dt=\pi/2$$

Any hints on how to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the interchange $t\leftrightarrow \frac{1}{t}$ we have that

$$I = \int_{0}^\infty \frac{dt}{c^2\left(t-\frac{m}{ct}\right)^2+ x^2}$$

The integral is even and converges so we can say

$$I = \frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{dt}{c^2\left(t-\frac{m}{ct}\right)^2 + x^2}$$

Lastly we'll use the theorem

$$p.v.\int_{-\infty}^\infty f\left(x-\frac{a}{x}\right)dx = p.v.\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)dx$$

for $a>0$ to get

$$I = \frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{dt}{c^2t^2+x^2} = \frac{\pi}{2|xc|}$$

assuming $mc>0$

Comment: What is the name of the used p.v. theorem which I didn't recall?

Comment: @MathArt it doesn't really have an agreed upon name having been rediscovered many times, but it is in Wolfram Mathworld under Glasser's Master Theorem.

Comment: I had the condition $mc>0$, but still wondering what if $mc<0$?

Comment: @MathArt I'm assuming this comes from a physics problem, so there is probably some sort of disaster if we have $mc<0$.

Comment: Sure it is indeed a physics formulation. So there will be no solution if $mc<0$?

Answer (score 1):

Rearrange the integral as follows

\begin{align}
& \int_0^\infty\frac{1}{x^2t^2}\frac{1}{(\frac{c}{xt}-\frac{mt}{x})^2+1}dt \\
=& \frac1{2cx} \int_0^\infty \frac{(\frac{c}{xt^2}+\frac mx)+ (\frac{c}{xt^2}-\frac mx )}{(\frac{c}{xt}-\frac{mt}{x})^2+1}dt\\
=& \frac1{2cx} \int_0^\infty \frac{d(\frac {mt }x-\frac{c}{xt})}{(\frac{c}{xt}-\frac{mt}{x})^2+1}
 -\frac1{2cx} \int_0^\infty \frac{d(\frac{c}{xt}+\frac {mt }x )}{(\frac{c}{xt}+\frac{mt}{x})^2+1-\frac{4cm}{x^2}}\\
\end{align}
where the first integral is of the form $\int_0^\infty\frac{du}{1+u^2}$ and the second integral vanishes.

Comment: Assumed that the next has to use the master theorem.

Comment: @MathArt - there is no need

Comment: I was deriving the formula for the second integral to vanish, but I think it needs to discuss the sign of $1-\frac{4cm}{x^2}$.

Comment: @MathArt - it vanishes due to the same limit values of $\frac{c}{xt}+\frac {mt }x$